# Tensorflow 2: How can I use the shape of tensor y_true in custom loss?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I pass a list `a` to my custom function and I want to `tf.tile` it after converting it to a constant tensor. The times I tile it depends on the shape of `y_true`. I don't know how I can get the shape of `y_true` as integers. Here's the code:

```py
def getloss(a):
    a = tf.constant(a, tf.float32)
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        a = tf.reshape(a, [1,1,-1])
        ytrue_shape = y_true.get_shape().as_list() #????
        multiples = tf.constant([ytrue_shape[0], ytrue_shape[1], 1], tf.int32)
        a = tf.tile(a, multiples)
        #...
    return loss
```

I have tried `y_true.get_shape().as_list()` but it reports an error because the first dimension (batch size) is `None` when compiling the model. Is there any way I can use the shape of `y_true` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When trying to access the shape of a tensor during the building of the model, when not all shapes are known, it is best to use [`tf.shape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape). It will be evaluated when the model is ran, as stated in the doc :

> tf.shape and Tensor.shape should be identical in eager mode. Within tf.function or within a compat.v1 context, not all dimensions may be known until execution time. Hence when defining custom layers and models for graph mode, prefer the dynamic tf.shape(x) over the static x.shape.

```py
ytrue_shape = tf.shape(y_true)
```

This will yield a Tensor, so use TF ops to get what you want :

```
multiples = tf.concat((tf.shape(y_true_shape)[:2],[1]),axis=0)
```

Comment: But `tf.shape(y_true)` gives a tensor, which means I cannot use ytrue_shape[0] or ytrue_shape[1] as integers in the sixth line.  If I use `tf.shape(y_true)` it will report an TypeError: Expected int32, got <tf.Tensor 'loss/KPD_Output_loss/strided_slice:0' shape=() dtype=int32> of type 'Tensor' instead.

Comment: Yes, it seemed obvious to me that you would need tensorflow ops to get what you wanted. I added a quick comment. I'll try to be more thorough next time.

Comment: Wow, I never thought  I can implement it in this way. You really enlightened me. Thank you a lot!